# Getting node-gyp to work on win64 - missing ammintrin.h

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2010, node-gyp

I've searched high and low but can't get any of the suggested solutions to work. I get this error when trying to build any npm package with a native component:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\intrin.h(26): fa
tal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ammintrin.h': No such file or direc
tory [C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Projects\WallOfShame\api\node_modules\bcrypt\buil
d\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
```

I uninstalled everything related to VS2010, including Win 7.1 SDK and all redistributables then reinstalled the windows 7.1 SDK and the Win 7.1 SDK Service Pack 1. I don't have visual studio installed or need it currently. Still getting this frustrating error message. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so for anyone wondering I just downloaded the header file and added it to the include directory. I could not for the life of me get it to work with any combination of SDKs, service packs, and redistributables.